# How to persist tomcat sessions across restarts while using IntelliJ idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

It seems intellij clears all tomcat related folders across a redeploy/restart. This means every time we restart tomcat from IntelliJ, we have to re-login to our app.

Is there any way to persist tomcat sessions across restarts when using it from within IntelliJ Idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IntelliJ configuration for a local Tomcat instance has a checkbox for "Preserve sessions across restarts". Check that, and the sessions should be preserved.

By the way, I've seen a number of developers waste a lot of time over the years messing around with the Tomcat plugins in Eclipse and IntelliJ, trying to figure out how to get them to work in a manner similar to production.

The easiest answer by far is to just use a regular Tomcat instance, and forego the IDE integration. One easy thing to do to replace this, if you are using Maven (you are using a build tool, aren't you?) is to use the [maven tomcat plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/).

Comment: is there anything like the maven tomcat plugin for gradle?

Comment: Yes, there is a gradle tomcat plugin. See https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin